# JAVA ME: Can't find the WMA Console

Tags: netbeans, java-me

I'm following a tutorial and I need to use the WMA Console, but I can't find it.

[Here says](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/jme-sdk-3.3/nb/html/wma.htm#Z400085a1297024) I should find it in Tools > Java ME > WMA Console , but obviously is not there

[image]

Or in the emulator :

[image]

Do I need to install or activate anything??

I'm using netbeans 8.0 and JAVA ME SDK 3.4

Answer (score 1):

don't know about the WMA console, maybe it is an obsolete version of netbeans, but use as stated in 22.3 Running WMA Tool

launch installdir\bin\wma-tool [command]

for instance if you want to receive sms it gives you a fake number to send sms to

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. In the end I had to do that, but I just thought someone might know how to enable that graphic console that is described in the link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to add oracle-jmesdk-8-3-nb-plugins to enable Java ME under which you can see the WMA console.

Thanks.